# Query database with comment meta

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

I have a wordpress comment box with 2 custom files, name and country, which get written to the database with the `meta_key` tag as `comment_name` and `comment_country`. What I need to do is display these comments which needs to include the actual comment, as well as the values of the 2 custom fields. I need to query the database as I need to retrieve ALL comments, not just comments for that particular page.

The code I (kind of) have is:

```
<?php 
global $wpdb;
$querystr = " SELECT comment_content FROM $wpdb->comments INNER JOIN $wpdb->commentmeta ON meta_key = 'comment_name'";
$comment_info =  $wpdb->get_results($querystr, OBJECT);
echo '<ul>';
// display the results
foreach($comment_info as $info) { 
echo '<li class="commentBox"><p>'. $info->comment_content .'</p><h6>'. $info->meta_value .'</h6></li>'; 
}
echo '</ul>';                            
?>
```

As you can probably see, I need to get the `comment_content` field which is in `wp_comments`, but also combine that with the `meta_value` of 2 `meta_keys`. I obviously haven't figured out how to try and add the second `meta_key`/value to my code.

Can anybody help me please as I am at my wits end with this!

**UPDATE:**
I can now query the info I need. I had to use aliases so I can query 2 different meta_keys with corresponding values. The code:

```
$querystr = 
" SELECT * FROM $wpdb->comments, $wpdb->commentmeta AS commentmeta1, $wpdb->commentmeta AS commentmeta2 
WHERE $wpdb->comments.comment_ID = commentmeta1.comment_id 
AND $wpdb->comments.comment_ID = commentmeta2.comment_id 
AND commentmeta1.meta_key = 'comment_name' 
AND commentmeta2.meta_key = 'comment_country' 
ORDER BY $wpdb->comments.comment_date DESC";

$comment_info =  $wpdb->get_results($querystr, OBJECT);
```

So what I now need to do is reference `commentmeta1` and `commentmeta2` in my loop to output the 2 different values. The code I am using:

```
echo '<ul>';
// display the results
foreach($comment_info as $info) { 
echo '<li class="commentBox"><p>' . $info->comment_content . '</p><h6>' . $info->meta_value['commentmeta1'] . ', ' . $info->meta_value['commentmeta2'] . '</h6></li>'; 
}
echo '</ul>';
```

The meta values don't output as they should, it basically takes the first letter only of my `commentmeta2` ('comment_country'), and duplicates it for each instance (pic below). If I query only one meta key I can display the value in my loop fine by simply running `$info->meta_value`. How can I simply my meta_values as per my query?

[image: Img of current output]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sussed it! Final working code is as follows:

```
$querystr = " SELECT comment_content, commentmeta1.meta_value AS comment_name, commentmeta2.meta_value AS comment_country 
FROM $wpdb->comments, $wpdb->commentmeta AS commentmeta1, $wpdb->commentmeta AS commentmeta2 
WHERE $wpdb->comments.comment_ID = commentmeta1.comment_id 
AND $wpdb->comments.comment_ID = commentmeta2.comment_id 
AND commentmeta1.meta_key = 'comment_name' 
AND commentmeta2.meta_key = 'comment_country' ORDER BY $wpdb->comments.comment_date DESC";

$comment_info =  $wpdb->get_results($querystr, OBJECT);

echo '<ul>';
// display the results
foreach($comment_info as $info) { 
echo '<li class="commentBox"><p>' . $info->comment_content . '</p>
<h6>' . $info->comment_name . ', ' . $info->comment_country . '</h6></li>'; 
}

echo '</ul>';
```

I basically needed to pass the alias into `SELECT` and assign a new alias which I could reference in my loop.

Answer (score 0):

How about specifying the columns you need in your `SELECT` statement:

```
SELECT comment_content, comment_name, comment_country FROM ...
```

Then reference them in your HTML as `$info->comment_name` and so on.

If you need more direction, you need to share the database schemas for your comments tables.

Comment: Thanks for replying Markus. I did what you suggested and with a bot of extra research I have made some progress. I have edited my question with what I did and the hurdle I face now!!

Comment: Wordpress databases are, um, interesting to say the least. I don't have an install handy to check out right now, but I know they're quite fond of structures that make for complex queries, such as listing each meta-field for a single entry in a separate row, and the "real field name" for each stored in a generic "meta_key_name" field or so. It may make things customizable without modifying table structures, but man, it's a pain in the asterisk to work with. Don't get me started on their taxonomy; for laffs, check this out: https://twitter.com/CodeSatori/status/504775322923847681